How does hashed index store data in mongodb?
I read that hashed index works by creating md5 hash of a field and associating it with a document. But what happens next? Is this the same as a dictionary in python? Do we create array to store pointers to documents and computing indexes of array associated with documents using received hashes?
I read official documentation and a couple of unofficial websites, but got 0 answers.

Hash indexes are primarily used for sharding of monotonically increasing keys, as it evenly distributes the hashes rather than clustering them. Why do you consider hash indexes?

@WernfriedDomscheit
I am preparing for a job interview. Must know how it works internally to optimize a database and queries to it.

I don't think so, because in MongoDB you don't use hash indexes to optimize any queries.

A hashed index is structured the same as a normal index.  The only difference is the mongod will hash the value of the indexed field when creating the keystring.
You can use the convertShardKeyToHashed function to see what the hased value would look like.
